# How to create scope using Azure CLI (az ad app)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-cli2, azure-ad-powershell-v2

Using the Azure CLI 2.x, I cannot find a way to "add a Scope" under the expose an API section in Azure AD Portal.

[image]

What I do see is if I pass the --identifier-uris when the app is created, the APP ID URI and a Scope get automatically set:

```
    `az ad app create --display-name "$appName" --identifier-uris "https://$tenantDomain/$appName" --reply-urls "$replyUrl" --oauth2-allow-implicit-flow true`
```

[image]

Not what I expected nor what I want

So, I removed --identifier-urls from the create command and added the scope I wanted in manually. then I see via manifest what I'm looking for under OAuth2Permissions as shown below.  Can I put this in manifest.json with a new guid and insert it somehow?

[image]

What CLI command supports the explicit support to define a Scope?
Then Adding a Client application I would need to select the defined Scope, how is this referenced?

Documentation is very sparse, IMO.  This reference is very helpful but nothing in here talks about adding scopes and clients. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad?view=azure-cli-latest.  Any help towards samples or documentation much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With help from the thread above, and a ton of trial-n-error plus a [pretty useful link](https://damienbod.com/2020/06/22/using-azure-cli-to-create-azure-app-registrations/), I was able to work out the CLI script to add scope using a windows environment.  PowerShell is not happy with 'jq' on windows and use of the back-tick had to be removed to get things working.  Now I need to solve adding preAuthorizedApplication with the CLI.

```
$userAccessScopeApi = '{
    "lang": null,
    "origin": "Application",        
    "adminConsentDescription": "Access CP Debug desc",
    "adminConsentDisplayName": "Access CP Debug",
    "id": "--- replaced in scripts ---",
    "isEnabled": true,
    "type": "Admin",
    "userConsentDescription": null,
    "userConsentDisplayName": null,
    "value": "Access"
}' | ConvertTo-Json | ConvertFrom-Json
`

Write-Host " -  1 read oauth2permissions"
#(az ad app show  --id $appid)
$appjson = (az ad app list --display-name $appName)         
$app = $appjson | ConvertFrom-Json
$oauth2Permissions = $app.oauth2Permissions
$oauth2Permissions[0].isEnabled = 'false'

$oauth2Permissionsjson = ConvertTo-Json -InputObject @($oauth2Permissions) 

Write-Host " -  2 disable oauth2Permission in Azure App Registration"
$oauth2Permissionsjson | Out-File -FilePath .\oauth2Permissionsold.json
az ad app update --id $appId --set oauth2Permissions=@oauth2Permissionsold.json

Write-Host " -  3 delete the default oauth2Permission"
az ad app update --id $appId --set oauth2Permissions='[]'

Write-Host " -  4 add the new scope required add the new oauth2Permissions values"
$oauth2PermissionsApiNew = $userAccessScopeApi | ConvertFrom-Json
$oauth2PermissionsApiNew[0].id = New-Guid
$oauth2PermissionsApiNew = ConvertTo-Json -InputObject @($oauth2PermissionsApiNew) 

# Write-Host "new oauth2permissions : " + $oauth2PermissionsApiNew" 
$oauth2PermissionsApiNew | Out-File -FilePath .\oauth2Permissionsnew.json
az ad app update --id $appId --set oauth2Permissions=@oauth2Permissionsnew.json

Write-Host " - Updated scopes (oauth2Permissions) for App Registration: $appId"`
```

Answer (score 10):

As of 7/29/22 the latest Azure CLI command "az ad app update" does not include the oauth2permissions anymore. If you try the above, you will bang you head and hopefully find this post. The new location of these permissions on the app regs are located at api.oauth2PermissionScopes as an array.

In order to get around this I used a combination of a few items from this post and had to get creative as the [Azure docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/healthcare-apis/register-application-cli-rest) are also still incorrect.

It still stands true that if you have an existing API exposed, you have to disable it to modify the scopes. If you have a fresh app registration you can apply this direct without issue. Hopefully this helps someone like me that has automations that are now broken due to the changes to how apps are registered and the manifest changes. If you don't know about changes to [app registrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-app-create), I recommend you review. If you got this far though, I assume you already did.

```
# Add API Read Scope: 
$scopeGUID = [guid]::NewGuid()
$scopeJSONHash = @{
    adminConsentDescription="$apiName on $svrAppRegName"
    adminConsentDisplayName="$apiName on $svrAppRegName" 
    id="$scopeGUID"
    isEnabled=$true
    type="User"
    userConsentDescription="$apiName on $svrAppRegName"
    userConsentDisplayName="$apiName on $svrAppRegName"
    value="$apiName"
}
$azAppOID = (az ad app show --id $serverApplicationId | ConvertFrom-JSON).id
$accesstoken = (Get-AzAccessToken -Resource "https://graph.microsoft.com/").Token
$header = @{
    'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
    'Authorization' = 'Bearer ' + $accesstoken
}
$bodyAPIAccess = @{
    'api' = @{
        'oauth2PermissionScopes' = @($scopeJSONHash)
    }
}|ConvertTo-Json -d 3

#You can try az rest, I used Invoke-RestMethod though.
#$graphURL="https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/$azAppOID" 
#az rest --method PATCH --uri $graphurl --headers $header --body $bodyAPIAccess

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Patch -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/$azAppOID" -Headers $header -Body $bodyAPIAccess
```

Comment: This is now the correct answer! Thanks - helped a lot. For others finding this - note the singular 'Permission' in 'oauth2PermissionScopes' (instead of the old 'oauth2permissions' plural). Got caught on this one

Comment: I find is completely mad that Microsoft don't document their own API properly.

Answer (score 6):

As **A2AdminGuy** mentioned, it is not possible to update the `oauth2Permissions` direct anymore, but you can still use `az ad app update`.

1. Execute the command `az ad app show --id $appClientId` and you will see that the `oauth2PermissionScopes` is inside the `api` now:

```
"api": {
    "acceptMappedClaims": null,
    "knownClientApplications": [],
    "oauth2PermissionScopes": [],
    "preAuthorizedApplications": [],
    "requestedAccessTokenVersion": null
}
```

2. You need to update the `api` property to be able to set the `oauth2PermissionScopes`:

```
$apiScopeId = [guid]::NewGuid().Guid
$apiScopeJson = @{
    requestedAccessTokenVersion = 2
    oauth2PermissionScopes      = @(
        @{
            adminConsentDescription = "$AppName on $EnvironmentAbbrev"
            adminConsentDisplayName = "$AppName on $EnvironmentAbbrev"
            id                      = "$apiScopeId"
            isEnabled               = $true
            type                    = "User"
            userConsentDescription  = "$AppName on $EnvironmentAbbrev"
            userConsentDisplayName  = "$AppName on $EnvironmentAbbrev"
            value                   = "authenticate"
        }
    )
} | ConvertTo-Json -d 4 -Compress

$apiUpdateBody = $apiScopeJson | ConvertTo-Json -d 4

az ad app update --id $apiClientId --set api=$apiUpdateBody --verbose
```

The `--verbose` parameter can be removed, but interestingly, the update command is a PATH request to the graph API.

Since it is a PATH request, you don't always need to send the whole `api` property, you can do two requests to update different properties and the previous one will not be affected.

3. This is how you can update a SPA `redirectUris`:

```
$appSpaJson = @{
    redirectUris = @("http://localhost:3000")
} | ConvertTo-Json -d 3 -Compress
    
$appUpdateBody = $appSpaJson | ConvertTo-Json -d 4

az ad app update --id $appClientId --set spa=$appUpdateBody
```

Comment: You mean Patch request to the api?

Answer (score 5):

From this article [Azure CLI: Create an Azure AD application for an API that exposes OAuth2 Permissions](https://anmock.blog/2020/01/10/azure-cli-create-an-azure-ad-application-for-an-api-that-exposes-oauth2-permissions/)

You can use the `az ad app update` command ([see documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-app-update))

You can then set an application’s property by using the optional parameter `–set`

1. Create a `oauth2-permissions.json` containing the permission:

   ```
   [
     {
       "adminConsentDescription": "Access CP Debug Desc",
       "adminConsentDisplayName": "Access CP Debug",
       "id": "85b8f1a0-0733-47dd-9af4-cb7221dbcb73",
       "isEnabled": true,
       "type": "Admin",
       "userConsentDescription": null,
       "userConsentDisplayName": null,
       "value": "Access"
     }
   ]
   ```
2. Run this script, it will create the app, disable the existing scope and add the new scope:

   ```
   # Create the app registration
   APP_REG=$(az ad app create --display-name myapi --identifier-uris https://myapi)

   # Get the app id
   APP_ID=$(echo $APP_REG | jq -r '.appId')

   # disable default exposed scope
   DEFAULT_SCOPE=$(az ad app show --id $APP_ID | jq '.oauth2Permissions[0].isEnabled = false' | jq -r '.oauth2Permissions')
   az ad app update --id $APP_ID --set oauth2Permissions="$DEFAULT_SCOPE"

   # Create new scopes from file 'oath2-permissions'
   az ad app update --id $APP_ID --set oauth2Permissions=@oauth2-permissions.json
   ```

Comment: Hi, this looks promising.  However, this line $DEFAULT_SCOPE=$(az ad app show --id $appId | jq '.oauth2Permissions[0].isEnabled = false' | jq -r '.oauth2Permissions')  Fails with 
jq : The term 'jq' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or ....  I'll see if there's another way.

Comment: Are you running on windows or linux ? `jq` is a json query package for bash/shell https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Comment: Running on windows.  I'm looking for an equivalent

Comment: if you use powershell `ConvertTo-Json` and `ConvertFrom-Json`, it should do the trick ?

Comment: If I know what to change, am i simply setting IsEnabled to false in the OAuthPermissions and then passing that JSON (the entire thing) back in the set?  I can isolate the JSON block with this command : az ad app list --display-name $appName --query [].oauth2Permissions[0]

Comment: yeah it is to disable the default scope before creating a new one

Comment: Hi, can you shoot me what the DEFAULT_SCOPE looks like from the original code?  I assumed it was either the entire app or the oauth2permissions block but nothing works.  I get deserialize errors like this "Unable to build a model: Cannot deserialize as [OAuth2Permission] an object of type <class 'str'>, DeserializationError: Cannot deserialize as [OAuth2Permission] an object of type <class 'str'>.  Looked in the docs but it doesn't come close to telling anyone.  Have you run this code successfully?

Answer (score 3):

Here's the approach I ended up with in bash on WSL Ubuntu, in the event it's useful for anyone else:

```bash
# replace all <value> blocks with your own value

# create app registration and extract appId
clientid=$(az ad app create \
    --display-name <name> \
    --query appId \
    --output tsv)

# generate a UUID for the scope
uuid=$(uuidgen)

# set the API object as a JSON object
api=$(echo '{
    "acceptMappedClaims": null,
    "knownClientApplications": [],
    "oauth2PermissionScopes": [{
        "adminConsentDescription": "<description>",
        "adminConsentDisplayName": "<name>",
        "id": "'$uuid'",
        "isEnabled": true,
        "type": "User",
        "userConsentDescription": "<description>",
        "userConsentDisplayName": "<name>",
        "value": "<value>"
    }],
    "preAuthorizedApplications": [],
    "requestedAccessTokenVersion": 2
}' | jq .)

# Update app registration with App ID URL and api object
az ad app update \
    --id $clientid \
    --identifier-uris api://$clientid \
    --set api="$api"
```

Comment: This was helpful but worth noting that content of the api property must include all that's required. So, if run against an existing app reg that already has permission scopes errors will be raised if those scopes are not first disabled

Comment: @RobBowman good to know, thanks for the heads up. I've been purely using this in the context of generating new app registrations.

Comment: This helped me a lot, I was trying to do `az ad app update --set oauth2Permissions="stuff"` and not `az ad app update --set api="a bit more stuff"`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the command that worked for me:

```bash
az ad app update --id ... --set api=@payload.json
```

And the contents of `payload.json`:

```json
{
  "oauth2PermissionScopes": [
    {
      "adminConsentDescription": "Authenticate",
      "adminConsentDisplayName": "Authenticate",
      "id": "3c8d0da4-8000-49ab-b406-e2d601a12900",
      "isEnabled": true,
      "type": "User",
      "value": "Authenticate"
    }
  ]
}
```

As an aside, before I wrote this answer, I tried *many* different strategies based on the varied answers to this question, but here's a list of things that *didn't* work for me:

- `az update --id ... --set api.oauth2PermissionScopes=...`: despite the documentation claiming this notation might work, I could not find a way to set nested properties.
- `az update --id ... --set api='{"oauth2PermissionScopes":[...]}'`: this is likely some type of shell quoting issues, but the `@`-file reference was the only way I could get the payload to take.
- `az update -id ... --set oauth2Permissions=...`: I believe this strategy conflates the name of this property in the app manifest with the name of the property in the underlying [MS Graph API call request body](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-body).

That being said, understanding that the `--set` flag is for setting the top-level properties (again, I never got nesting to work) of a request body to a `PATCH` call was the key for me. And since it's a `PATCH`, sending partial bodies is fine and won't blow away existing settings. For example, even though I believe there's flag for this, you can do:

```bash
az update -id ... --set displayName=blah
```

In the end, I find the `az ad app update --set` command to provide a tiny but of sugar over a direct API call with `az rest`.