# How do I add a scope in AD B2C App Registration using AZ CLI

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to create an app registration in Azure AD B2C. I need to add a scope using Azure CLI  (which can be added by going to Expose a API blade in portal)

I can retrieve my app using

```
az rest --method GET --uri https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/id
```

[image]

But when I run the following command

```
az ad app update --id 'id' --set api.oauth2PermissionScopes=@scopes.json
```

I get this error
`Couldn't find 'api' in ''. Available options: []`

Here is the scopes.json file

```json
{
    "api": {
      "oauth2PermissionScopes": [
        {
          "type": "User",
          "isEnabled": true,
          "adminConsentDisplayName": "deafult",
          "adminConsentDescription": "deafult",
          "id": "73a43c0e-9a5e-4646-9d1e-c56a43279f99",
          "value": "deafult",
          "userConsentDisplayName": "deafult",
          "userConsentDescription": "deafult"
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

The latest Azure CLI command **`"az ad app update"`** does not include the oauth2permissions anymore.

I tried with below scripts and added scope successfully.

```
$AppId ="your application id"
$scopeGUID = [guid]::NewGuid()
$permission = @{
    adminConsentDescription="admin only"
    adminConsentDisplayName="readwrite" 
    id="$scopeGUID"
    isEnabled=$true
    type="User"
    userConsentDescription="null"
    userConsentDisplayName="null"
    value="readwrite"
}
$azAppObjId = (az ad app show --id $AppId | ConvertFrom-JSON).id
$accesstoken = (Get-AzAccessToken -Resource "https://graph.microsoft.com/").Token
$header = @{
    'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
    'Authorization' = 'Bearer ' + $accesstoken
}
$bodyaccess = @{
    'api' = @{
        'oauth2PermissionScopes' = @($permission)
    }
}|ConvertTo-Json -d 3
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Patch -Headers $header -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/$azAppObjId" -Body $bodyaccess
```

***Powershell:***
[image]

**Portal:**
[image]

Also checked with commands:

```
 az ad app show --id < application id >
```

**Output:**
[image]

**Reference:**
Please refer the similar kind of [SO-Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62665491/how-to-create-scope-using-azure-cli-az-ad-app) which is resolved by A2AdminGuy.