# How to Set Azure App scope after creating the new App using Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-cli, azure-cli2, azure-ad-powershell-v2

I am trying to create an app and try to create scope for that, I am able to create the app but I am unable to create the scope. I already tired to search for the solution, I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73171550/4727492) but it seems like it's outdated.

Here is the script for the creating of the app:

```
$appId = az ad app create --display-name "webapp - dev" --sign-in-audience "AzureADMyOrg" --required-resource-accesses "./appregistration/script.json" --query appId -o tsv
```

I have a file called permissions.json for the scope.

```
[
{
    "adminConsentDescription": "Allow the app to access Api endpoints",
    "adminConsentDisplayName": "webApi",
    "id": null,
    "isEnabled": true,
    "type": "Admin",
    "userConsentDescription": null,
    "userConsentDisplayName": null,
    "value": "webApi"
}
```

]

I am trying to get data from this file and creating a scope. here's a script for that.

```
 $json = Get-Content './appregistration/permissions.json' | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json

foreach ($element in $json)
{$element.id = [guid]::NewGuid() }
 $apiScopeJson = @{oauth2PermissionScopes = $json}
 az ad app update --id $appId --set api=$apiScopeJson
```

I am getting this error message.

Property api in payload has a value that does not match schema.

Answer (score 0):

I used similar code by ***@A2AdminGuy*** from same [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62665491/how-to-create-scope-using-azure-cli-az-ad-app?noredirect=1&lq=1) you mentioned in the question and able to add new scope to application successfully:

```
$AppId = az ad app create --display-name "webapp - dev" --sign-in-audience "AzureADMyOrg" --query appId -o tsv
Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
$scopeGUID = [guid]::NewGuid()
$permission = @{
    adminConsentDescription="Allow the app to access Api endpoints"
    adminConsentDisplayName="webApi" 
    id="$scopeGUID"
    isEnabled=$true
    type="Admin"
    userConsentDescription="null"
    userConsentDisplayName="null"
    value="webApi"
}
$AppObjId = (az ad app show --id $AppId | ConvertFrom-JSON).id

$appIduri = az ad app update --id $AppObjId --identifier-uris api://$AppId 


$accesstoken = (Get-AzAccessToken -Resource "https://graph.microsoft.com/").Token
$header = @{
    'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
    'Authorization' = 'Bearer ' + $accesstoken
}
$bodyaccess = @{
    'api' = @{
        'oauth2PermissionScopes' = @($permission)
    }
}|ConvertTo-Json -d 3

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Patch -Headers $header -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/$AppObjId" -Body $bodyaccess
```

**PowerShell Output:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal, new **application** created with **new scope** as below:

[image]